# Construction of polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I am asked to construct a polynomial f(x) at the lowest grade possible where x = 2 is a double zero point, x = -1 is one zero and f(0) = 2.

Im not sure how a double zero point would look like for one x. Can the graph cut several times trough the same x-value?

What ive come up with so far is this:

f(x) = (x-2)(x-2)(x+1) (x+0.5)

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29+%3D+%28x-2%29%28x-2%29%28x%2B1%29+%28x%2B0.5%29

It certainly meets the criteria in that f(0) = 2 and it has a zero at -1 and +2 but as i said, im not sure what a "double-zero" would look like for x = 2

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a polynomial $f(x) = a(x - \alpha_1)\cdots(x - \alpha_n)$, we say that the root $\alpha_i$ has multiplicity $m$ if the factor $(x - \alpha_i)$ appears $m$ times. So you are correct in constructing a polynomial with a factor of $(x - 2)^2$. However, the question also asks you to minimize the degree (I assume this is what you mean by grade). You chose to add a fourth root to satisfy the condition $f(0) = 2$. However, remember you can add a constant factor. So the correct answer is
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x - 2)^2(x + 1),$$
as this has degree $3$.

Comment: Yes sorry, ment degree by grade, not used to the english notations :). Very simple method indeed to add the constant! Thank you very much!

Comment: ps. will add as correct answer once stackexchange will let me :)